# Can ng-list return an array of numbers instead of strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following input (nested in an ng-repeat).

```
<input ng-model="event.days" ng-list required>
```

The problem is, whenever the user edits the value of this input (for example, changing:

```
1, 2
```

to

```
1, 2, 3
```

the array changes from an array of integers, like

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

to an array of strings

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

I realize that the documentation clearly states that this is what ng-list does. I'm just wondering what the least intense work-around for this issue is. I've already tried adding:

```
ng-change="event.days = event.days.map(parseInt);"
```

But that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can clone *ngList* to your let's say *intList* directive, and just add there `parseInt` function:

```
app.directive('intList', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 100,
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      var ngList = attr.ngList || ', ';
      var trimValues = attr.ngTrim !== 'false';
      var separator = trimValues ? ngList.trim() : ngList;

      var parse = function(viewValue) {
        // If the viewValue is invalid (say required but empty) it will be `undefined`
        if (!angular.isDefined(viewValue)) return;

        var list = [];

        if (viewValue) {
          angular.forEach(viewValue.split(separator), function(value) {
            if (value) list.push(parseInt(trimValues ? value.trim() : value));
          });
        }

        return list;
      };

      ctrl.$parsers.push(parse);
      ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        if (angular.isArray(value)) {
          return value.join(ngList);
        }

        return undefined;
      });

      // Override the standard $isEmpty because an empty array means the input is empty.
      ctrl.$isEmpty = function(value) {
        return !value || !value.length;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mEBm05gnfyM03xy9QlZh?p=preview

Comment: This works perfectly. I would have never thought of just cloning/customizing ng-list!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the behaviour of `ng-list`. The value of the `input` is always a string so this is what will go to `event.days`.

You could always do some parsing like:

```
daysArray = daysString.split("\\s+").map(day => parseInt(day, 10))
```

Comment: Ah ok I understand! But where could I put something like that? It doesn't work in ng-change.